# Getting 400 error response code when executing a provisioning request (https://www.googleapis.com/certificateprovisioning/v1/devicecertificates/create

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, drm, android-drm

I'm implementing DRM for my app but the request for getting a provisioning certificate is not working. This is an example of the generated url (POST) https://www.googleapis.com/certificateprovisioning/v1/devicecertificates/create?key=AIzaSyB-5OLKTx2iU5mko18DfdwK5611JIjbUhE&signedRequest=CloKTAgAEkgAAAACAAAWOhe56yXvv4bS5HsN9tcC1CDSSeLQ33QhETq_xJainehEOj9ydrcwebiZ-oGsQJqImOAtmGLp7I12QOBURBH0oPESBFh4r1oaBAgAEgASIG2kLvPaj2acjLz9TCUxWtI6PcOjr97TmOj4_5dlb8xO, but this request seems much sorter than [this one](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5129#issuecomment-443273682) for example. My code to generate the url is the same as in the ExoPlayer source

```
@Override
public byte[] executeProvisionRequest(UUID uuid, ProvisionRequest request)
        throws MediaDrmCallbackException {
    String url =
            request.getDefaultUrl() + "&signedRequest=" + Util.fromUtf8Bytes(request.getData());
    return executePost(
            dataSourceFactory,
            url,
            /* httpBody= */ null,
            /* requestProperties= */ Collections.emptyMap());
}
```

I've also tried to use [HttpMediaDrmCallback](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/drm/HttpMediaDrmCallback.html) from ExoPlayer and it's not working either. I guess request.getData() is wrong. The request happens when I tested on a Nexus 9 with Android 7.1.1, if I try with Android 10/11 it works fine. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It works by forcing Widevine L3